# VBA : Overflow error

Tags: excel, vba, overflow

I have an error i don't understand why

I have a function i didn't touch (without error) and now it's didn't work...
My function has just on line

I tried the function CDbl() and use the double type variable

I get an Overflow error

Number = 1341.0937961001

NbDecimal = 2

```
Function Truncate(Number As Double, NbDecimal As Integer) As Double
    Truncate = Int(Number * 10 ^ NbDecimal) / (10 ^ NbDecimal)
End Function 'Error here : Overflow
```

I need help

Comment: I tried running this with the values you provided and it works. So can you supply the code you use to run this?

Comment: I, too, cannot reproduce the error using the code and values in your post.

Comment: Sorry the problem has not this function but the next. I resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

It will overflow when Number * 10 ^ nbDecimal exceeds 32767 because thats the largest number VBA will store in an integer.

Actually I am wrong: it will only overflow if you use CInt() rather than Int()

Comment: I cannot reproduce that using his code.  With his code and his values, `Number * 10 ^ nbDecimal` =  134109.37961001   and the code runs without error.  I would expect a problem if nbDecimal > 32767  (Excel 2016)

Answer (score 0):

To add to What Charles Williams was saying, you might want to change your data type to Long.